# Javafx: Can't import custom control into Scene Builder

Tags: eclipse, javafx, jar, scenebuilder

I tried to import my gui control (jar file) into the scene builder but without success. The file was created using eclipse export -> jar. When it was selected in scene builder "import JAR/FXML File", there was nothing inside the Import Dialog.

My control is a TextField with TextFormatter:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;


public class CustomTextField extends TextField {

    public CustomTextField() {
        setText("Custom");

        NumberTextFormatter formatter = new NumberTextFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {
                return object.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                try {
                    return NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(string);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

        });

        setTextFormatter(formatter);

    }

    public static class NumberTextFormatter extends TextFormatter<Number> {

        public NumberTextFormatter(StringConverter<Number> valueConverter) {
            super(valueConverter);
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure that the culprit is the usage of TextFormatter. Because the control will works (appear in Import Dialog) if I removed the TextFormatter from the codes.

Whats wrong?

Update: Even if I simplified my constructor to exclude setTextFormatter(), as long as it still have a line of TextFormatter declaration the problem still persist. Such as:

```
public CustomTextField() {
    setText("Custom");

    TextFormatter<Integer> formatter = new TextFormatter<Integer>(new IntegerStringConverter());
}
```

Comment: What if you return something other than `null` from the catch block, such as `0` or `Double.NaN`?

Comment: @Slaw changed to 0 or Double.NaN doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The oracle scene builder 2.0 is too old/ too dumb to work with TextFormatter. Need to upgrade to Gluon scene builder 8.5.0.